# Obtener palabra mas frecuente y numero de veces que se repite en un archivo

Tags: apache-spark

Estoy leyendo un archivo y contando las palabras para mostrar cuantas veces se repite cada una.

```
readme = sc.textFile("README.md")

wordCounts = readme.flatMap(lambda line: line.split()).map(lambda word: (word, 
1)).reduceByKey(lambda a, b: a+b)

wordCounts.collect()
```

Devuelve lo siguiente:

> [('#', 1),
> ('Apache', 1),
> ***('Spark', 14),***
> ('is', 6),
> ('It', 2),
> ('provides', 1),
> ('high-level', 1),
> ('APIs', 1),
> ('in', 5),
> ('Scala,', 1),
> ('Java,', 1),
> ('an', 3),
> ('optimized', 1),
> ('engine', 1),
> ('supports', 2),
> ('computation', 1),
> ('analysis.',1),
> ('set', 2),
> ('of', 5),
> ('tools', 1),
> ('SQL', 2),
> ('MLlib', 1),
> ('machine', 1),
> ('learning,', 1),
> ('GraphX', 1),
> ('graph', 1),
> ('processing,', 1),
> ('Documentation', 1),
>
> ..... (Hay mas datos pero lo corte acá)]

Como se ve la palabra que mas se repite es Spark con 14 registros, ahora:

**¿Como puedo mostrar solamente esa palabra y el total de registros?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya lo encontre era con la funcion takeOrdered usando una lambda en la key ordenando del total de key's la ultima

```
wordCounts.takeOrdered(1, key = lambda x: -x[1])
```

> output: [('Spark', 14)]

Tambien se puede de esta forma:

```
wordCounts.reduce(lambda a, b: a if (a[1] > b[1]) else b)
```

> output: [('Spark', 14)]